# How to copy only new files AND only those that are modified after a certain date?

Tags: windows, robocopy, xcopy

I would like to copy files from one drive to another, but I only want to copy source files that are newer than the destination file.  **BUT**, I also want to only copy source files that have been changed after a certain date.

I know I can use xcopy to do either one of these things, but I would like to do both at the same time.

So for example, I want to copy all source files dated on or after 3/1/2013, but in addition I only want the file copied if the source file is newer than the destination.  So ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
xcopy c:\*.* e:\*.* /D:03-01-2013
```

combined with something like this:

```
xcopy c:\*.* e:\*.* /D
```

Can this be done with xcopy or Robocopy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will probably get you what you want:

```
Robocopy c:\ e:\ *.* /MAXAGE:20130301 /XO /E
```

**Add the `/L` command to this to see what it will do without it actually doing it first just to make sure.**

Check [here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) for more information on Robocopy's options.

Answer (score 2):

Just use both options in the same command:

```
xcopy c:\*.* e:\*.* /D /D:03-01-2013
```

gets you what you want.

Comment: How would you do it if you wanted the file to be at least 1 hour old? In other words, a relative age from now, not an absolute age?

Comment: @toddmo It looks like both xcopy and Robocopy can only filter by date, not time. You would have to use some other utility, or something like a FOR loop with the DIR /O:D command.

Comment: [RoboCopy can use minage and maxage](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), but it is only on the day level, not hour. You can also read here for some other tools and batch scripts that will [copy files 1 hour old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047965/how-can-i-copy-only-files-and-folder-created-in-the-past-hour-in-one-directory-t).

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to do the same without command line, the SyncToy tool does the job pretty well.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=15155